# How can I send someone my app through internet

Tags: java, android

I have built an Android app using Android Studio and I need to download the app on some other phone. I can't access the phone physically, so I can't connect it to my computer via USB and install it on the phone. I need a way to send the app files to the user via internet so that they can download and install and test the app. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: (LMGTFY) I think you are looking for Firebase App Distribution.

Comment: As @TheLibrarian said, Firebase App Distribution works, or for a more caveman solution you can export the app to an APK file and send that to the user

Comment: I just wanna clarify. LMGTFY was just about that it is very easy to find things about this. I use App Distribution. They have very good gradle integration where you can compile and automatically upload it for distribution. but again this is VERY broad question without any "problem" as seen in SO terms.

Comment: This isn't a broad question at all. You need to relax and be simple. I'm in need of a way to send the app to another phone via internet. How is this broad? You are supposed to give me anything that is going to help me with this and i'll try all of them out. This website is also in google so i did google too. Ease out big guy.